# Why does tidyverse show all columns as col_double() when reading data into a tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse

When I read in data to a tidyverse tibble it shows all the columns as `col_double()`. What does the `col_double` mean here?

[image]

When I check the tibble using the base R `str()` function all of the data has been read in as the correct types.[image]

When I check the type of the tibble it returns list.
[image]

This all boils down to three main questions for me:

1. What is the meaning of `col_double`?
2. Does tidyverse have an alternative to the `str()` function to check column data types?
3. What is the proper way to check if an object is a tibble?

Comment: `double` is used is many languages as a particular type of non-integer numeric value. Including C, which R is built on. Nothing here looks surprising or wrong. Use `is_tibble` to check if something is a tibble. Or `class()`, and look for `tbl_df` as one of the classes.

Comment: `dplyr::glimpse` is a `tidyverse` equivalent of `str`.

Comment: And you can see `tbl` and `tbl_df` among the classes in the first line of output from `str()`.

Comment: @Gregor7 Thanks for the comment. So are col_character() and col_double() just the functions being used by tidyverse to read in the data? Or is this showing the type of data? Or both?

Comment: @revans Thank you for the tip. dplyr::glimpse doesn't give the data types though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double` is a fairly standard term in programming languages for (usually, but not necessarily) non-integer numbers. R doesn't use the term much (using `numeric` instead), but C uses doubles and R is built on C. If you're interested in learning more, [here's the Wikipedia page: Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

`readr` uses `col_double()` to (strictly) parse numeric columns. See the help page `?col_double` for some more details, and the package vignette [Introduction to readr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/vignettes/readr.html) for much more detail. By default, `readr` will guess what each of your columns are, and then use the appropriate parsing function for each type, such as `col_double` for non-integer numerics.

The best way to check if something is a tibble, is `is_tibble`. You can also use `class()` or `str()` (which prints class info), and look to see if `tbl_df` is among the classes.

`tidyverse` functions consistently use the term `double`, sometimes abbreviated to `dbl`, instead of `numeric`. You can see this in the printing of tibbles or in the `glimpse` method:

```
> as_tibble(head(iris))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 

> glimpse(head(iris))
Observations: 6
Variables: 5
$ Sepal.Length <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4
$ Sepal.Width  <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9
$ Petal.Length <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7
$ Petal.Width  <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4
$ Species      <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa

## str (from base R) uses `num` instead of `<dbl>`
> str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading the [documentation for reading delimited files](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) from the `readr` package.

1. When you use `read_csv()`, R guesses the appropriate variable type for each column. The message, "*Parsed with column specification*", provides detail of the variables and their detected types. A "double", is essentially a non-integer numeric variable.
2. Tibbles always display the variable types upon output. (for example view link above) An alternative is to use `glimpse()`, but you can still use `str()`.
3. You can check is an object is a tibble using `is_tibble()`